# After upgrading to 1.4, my directive tag model doesn't work anymore

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-show

Recently we upgraded to 1.4 and now I'm having a problem with the way this hover directive works.

Previously working code:

```
angular
    .module('tagHoverDirective', []).controller('TagsHover', TagsHover)
    .directive('tagsHover', directive);

function directive () {
    var directive = {
        templateUrl : "popovers/tagsPopovers/tagsHover.html",
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        bindToController: true,
        controller: TagsHover
        link: link,
        scope: {
            tag:'=ngModel'
        }
    };
    return directive;
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {}
}

TagsHover.$inject = [
    '$scope',
    '$timeout'];

function TagsHover(
    $scope,
    $timeout) {
    ....
```

Now 1.4 forces us to use the `Controller as syntax`, I had to change up the `function directive ()` part to this:

```
function directive () {
    var directive = {
        templateUrl : "popovers/tagsPopovers/tagsHover.html",
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        bindToController: true,
        controller: 'TagsHover as tgh',
        link: link,
        scope: {
            tag:'=ngModel'
        }
    };
    return directive;
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {}
}
```

Now the `ng-show` in the markup no longer works, but how do I fix it? I'm not using `tgh` or `this`, I'm actually using the `tag` object that is getting passed into this directive to set the visibility.

```
<div class="tags-hover-container" ng-show="tag.tagsHoverDisplay">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually when you expose controllerAs you are binding "as" part to scope.

So $scope.anything becomes "as".anything.

You are exposing controller as

```
controller: 'TagsHover as tgh',
```

that means you are binding $scope/this to object tgh. So scope.tag becomes tgh.tag

Your template now should be

```
<div class="tags-hover-container" ng-show="tgh.tag.tagsHoverDisplay">
```

Comment: Thanks! Was hoping it was simple - 8 mins